# Basic Ruby. Why is this method returning nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Hi!**

I am expecting `#<PrettyThing:0x0055a958175348 @success="anything here">`

but I am getting `'anything here'` instead. Any idea why?

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :success

  def execute
    self.success = execute!
  rescue
    self.success = false
  ensure
    self
  end
end

class PrettyThing < Thing
  def execute!
    'anything here'
  end
end

p PrettyThing.new.execute # => 'anything here'
```

Comment: Why are you even using ensure? Just have the `rescue..end`, then `self`. There is absolutely no need for `ensure` here.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 If I do that, if I remove the ensure and just add 'end', well, that'd be the end of the method. Or do you mean I should add a begin at the top instead?

Comment: Just remove the ensure part. Replace `ensure` with an `end`, and remove the first `end` under `self` to edit your exact example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure is a tricky thing. Normally, it doesn't return a value, and instead the return value from the last executed line of the main or rescue block is returned, unless there was an  uncaught error, then the error is returned. But, if you explicitly return, then you will get the return value. This is a bit nonstandard and confusing though, because the intent of the `ensure` clause is for silent cleanup. It may be better to move your return value outside your `begin`/`rescue` block.

Comment: Thank you. You are good. Your comment really helped me. I hacked it with a 'return' but your comment has made me realise so much more and yes.. you are right, it's obscure. Better to add an 'end' and then return naturally.

Comment: I would argue that the behaviour of 'ensure' is just as obscure as my code is :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :success

  def execute
    self.success = execute!
    self
  rescue
    self.success = false
  end
end

class PrettyThing < Thing
  def execute!
    'anything here'
  end
end

p PrettyThing.new.execute # => <PrettyThing:0x0000000379ea48 @success="anything here">
```

The way you have it written, `execute` is returning the assignment result of `self.success = execute!`. By adding `self`, you return the instance of `PrettyThing`.

This is handy if you want to chain methods, like:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :success

  def execute
    self.success = execute!
    self
  rescue
    self.success = false
  end

  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

end

class PrettyThing < Thing
  def execute!
    'anything here'
  end
end

p PrettyThing.new.execute.foo # => foo
```

Given your comment, I think I'd probably do it something more like:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :success

  alias success? success

  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

end

class PrettyThing < Thing

  def execute
    @success = everything_worked
    self
  end

private

  def everything_worked
    # your logic goes here
    # return true if all is good
    # return false or nil if all is not good
    true
  end

end

pretty_thing = PrettyThing.new.execute
p pretty_thing.success? # => true
```

If `everything_worked` returns `false` or `nil`, then `pretty_thing.success?` will also return `false` or `nil`.

Comment: isn't the ensure block then redundant (and effectively a no-op) in this case?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner - sorry, I was copying and pasting too fast. Updated. BTW, that `rescue` block looks funky anyhow. But, that's not the OP's root problem.

Comment: @jvillian why does it look funny? It's my ServiceBase. All services will inherit from it. And I want them all to fail silently so that the controller can then gracefully ask "service.success?" and if that's false I can return nice 500s VS just crashing. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @jvillian BTW Thank you so much for the answer. I +1'd it as it's helpful and descriptive. I was certainly not expecting this behaviour by a simple "ensure". Typical Ruby. Meh :)